# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 103.133.214.183:8080 in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I am Just new to Nodejs. I build some APIs and upload the code on live server( http://hrm.unibillapp.com:8080) where It was also working Fine
If I test these APIs on Postman but if I use these APIs in react Program  the server gets  stop and I got the following error

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 103.133.214.183:8080

and then I have to restart the server.

But there was one problem  when I was  running  the APIs code  that was on localhost . And I use these APIs in my same react program ,then if I hit login API It shows the consoles only one  time . but then If I hit other APIs then it shows Consoles  endlessly like it gets stuck in loop.  but it works fine when I hit these APIs on postman.

so I just want to know if there is the problem in my Node Program or react program.

I searched about it  but they are saying to handle this error but problem is I am not getting  this error on postman whether the code is on localhost  or on server .

I don't know what to do . please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Any error logs? Seems like you are sending an invalid request to your API which the server doesn't handle correctly. Might go into an endless loop, might crash. Impossible to say without additional information

Comment: no, there is not any error logs .and I have already create a middleware to handle invalid request.